# Suppose that $B$ is a disjoint set of subsets of $\Bbb N$: if $A,A' \in B$ and $A \neq A'$, then $A \cap A' = \emptyset$. Show that B is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Suppose that $B$ is a disjoint set of subsets of $\Bbb N$: if $A,A' \in B$ and $A \neq A'$, then $A \cap A'  = \emptyset$. Show that B is countable.

---

Does my proof look fine or contain logical gaps and flaws? Thank you so much for your verification!

---

**My attempt:**

---

**Lemma:** Let $\mathfrak P$ be a partition of $\Bbb N$. Then $\mathfrak P$ is countable.

**Proof**

If not, then $\mathfrak P$ is uncountable. It's clear that $\{\min X\mid X\in \mathfrak P\}$ and $\mathfrak P$ are equinumerous. Thus $\{\min X\mid X\in \mathfrak P\}$ is uncountable. On the other hand, $\{\min X\mid X\in \mathfrak P\}\subseteq \Bbb N$, then $\{\min X\mid X\in \mathfrak P\}$ is countable. This leads to a contradiction. Hence $\mathfrak P$ is countable.

---

We proceed to prove our main theorem.

It's clear that $B\subseteq \mathfrak P$ and $\mathfrak P$ is countable by **Lemma**. Then $B$ is countable. This completes the proof.

Comment: Whenever someone writes "it's clear," it usually means that there is a gap in the proof at that point...

Comment: "It's clear that $B\subseteq \mathfrak{B}$."  Not necessarily.  For trivial example, let $B=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ and let $\mathfrak{B}=\{\Bbb N\}$.  You introduced $\mathfrak{B}$ as simply being some arbitrary partition of $\Bbb N$ and did not bother relating it to $B$ in any way at the time of it's introduction.  You could have instead *constructed* $\mathfrak{B}$ using $B$ instead by letting $\mathfrak{B} = B\cup \{\Bbb N\setminus (\bigcup B)\}$.

Comment: It would be clearer in my opinion to show $f~:~B\to \Bbb N$ given by $f(A)=\min(A)$ is an injection, which by theorem implies $|B|\leq |\Bbb N|$.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake @JMoravitz! Your approach is definitely better.

Comment: Let me add that you're not using any contradictions there. It's a direct proof. Why do you need to assume that your family is uncountable, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the statement I deduce that you're using *countable* in the sense of

> *either finite or equinumerous with $\mathbb{N}$*

In this case, the statement that a partition of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable is correct. If $\mathfrak{B}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{N}$, then you can define
$$
f\colon\mathfrak{B}\to\mathbb{N}
\qquad
f(A)=\min A
$$
which is an injective map. This is what you did.

There is a small detail: a partition, by definition, doesn't contain the empty set, but your set $B$ might.

Moreover you are failing to *produce* a suitable partition which $B$ is a subset of.

Let's call *quasipartition* of $X$ a set $\mathfrak{B}$ of subsets of $X$ such that $\mathfrak{B}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ is a partition of $X$. Then every quasipartition of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, because adding one element to a countable set produces a countable set.

Now consider your set $B$. If $B_0=\bigcup_{A\in B}A$, then
$$
\mathfrak{B}=B\cup\{\mathbb{N}\setminus B_0\}
$$
is a quasipartition of $\mathbb{N}$ (prove it).

Answer (score 1):

Each set of B, discarding a possible empty set, has at least one point.  As the sets of B are pairwise disjoint, |B| <= |$\cup$B| <= |N|.  Thus B is countable.

Comment: "*Does my proof look fine or contain logical gaps and flaws?*", how is your answer helpful, then?